# Windowed Min-max transformation

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, normalization

Is there any easy way to perform min-max Transformation in a window of lets say 2000 sample point rather on whole data?

```
np.shape(X)
(10278, 4)

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_norm = scaler.fit_transform(X)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am curious of the pertinence of a min/max scaling using a rolling window. I believe this should introduce noise and/or artifacts as each window will be susceptible to the bounds.

Nevertheless, if I understood correctly, here is a way to achieve it:

input test data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.sin(np.arange(2000)/100+np.arange(4)[:, None])+np.random.normal(scale=0.2, size=(4,2000))).T
df.plot.line()
```

[image: input data]

min/max scaled data:

```
df_scaled = df.rolling(window=40, min_periods=1).apply(lambda a: ((a.iloc[0]-a.min())/(a.max()-a.min())))
df_scaled.plot.line()
```

[image: output data]

##### Same on non-noisy data

input:

[image: non-noisy input]

output:

[image: non-noisy output]

Comment: The peak amplitude of electropherograms in DNA/ RNA sequencing are observed to decay with time due to chemical and laser source imperfections, system configuration and variations in detector sensitivity. So, it is better to normalize it in some appropriate window size

https://ampliconexpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Microsatellite_Repeat.jpg

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I hope it will work on your real-life data ;)

Comment: unfortunately this solution does not work correctly , if change window size to larger , there is strange behavior

Comment: Well, as I told you, min/max with a window is highly susceptible to bounds. For instance of you have [9, 6, 7, 6, 1], this gives you [1, 0, 1, 1, 1] (window=3), which distorts completely the original signal. Have you tried standardizing on the rolling mean? Can you provide the chromatogram data?

Comment: ''Amplitude of a chromatogram trace is observed to decay
with time as a result of the variations in the dynamic range
of the trace signal. Each channel of the chromatogram trace
is initially segmented into non-overlapping consecutive
windows of 2000 sample points in width. The data in each
window are then normalized by its maximum amplitude to
the [0-1] range. Figure 4 illustrates the trace signals before
applying normalization while figure 5 shows the trace signal
after normalization.''

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5596983

Comment: in this paper they performed without any noise issue